# How Look for a value and bring next row, but not repeat?

Tags: excel-formula, return-value

I am trying to create an ordering file, it has 2 tabs, one with the official order form, and the next tab with the items they can order. I want to automatize the order tab, so i added check boxes next to each item and linked to a row next to it where it shows "TRUE" if checked and "FALSE" if not checked. I have also added another row with an if formula to simply look for that cell and if "True" show "X".

My question is, how can i write a formula to look for all items marked with "X" and automatically fill my order? I want to add the formula to all rows on the order form, so if they select 10 items they would show (but not repeat), and if they only selected one it would show only 1.

In the pic below, if they checked the box it would show on the other sheet with quantity and the CASE UPC

In the First picture shows where they would make the selection

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKx1U.png)

In the second picture shows where the formula would bring the qty and UPC Case code

[image]

I am trying to do something like VLOOKUP, but VLOOKUP would stop in the first match and repeat it. Thank You so much!

Answer (score 0):

If one has the dynamic array formula available in Office 365, put this in the upper left cell of the output area:

```
=FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},G:G,E:E),I:I="X")
```

Comment: Thank You! My Office 365 version does not include Dynamic Array Formulas. I tried on my personal PC which does and it works, but when i transferred to my work PC it did not work. I cannot manually update Office on my work PC.